# Method getModule returning unnamed module for class in named module

Tags: java, java-9

I just started to have a look at the Java 9 module system and I was wondering whether it is possible for a class to know in which module it is located.

Therefor I created the following module

```
module de.test {
  exports de.test.myexport;
}
```

and compiled a jar file that looks like

```
> jar --print-module-descriptor --file=Java9Test-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar                                

de.test
  requires mandated java.base
  exports de.test.myexport
```

In package `de.test`, I have a class called `Overview` where I'm calling

```
Module module = Overview.class.getModule();
```

However, the returned module object is unnamed and has no `ModuleDescriptor`.

Am I using `getModule()` correctly here, or is there any other way to load the module of a class?

I'm using JDK 9 build 120 on OS X.

Comment: WOW, Java9 being tested by Stiftung Warentest [:-)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

All JARs on the class path (with `java --class-path ...`) get bundled into the same so-called [unnamed module](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jigsaw/spec/sotms/#the-unnamed-module), regardless of whether they are "a real module" or "just a JAR". When you ask a class from such a JAR for its module, you get the result you describe.

Try putting the JAR on the module path (with `java --module-path ...`) and `Class::getModule` should return what you expect.

Comment: Thanks, it worked exactly as you described. To me, however, it seems not verity intuitive that `Class::getModule` behaves differently depending on how a class is executed.